# Git: Export MySQL database on commit?

Tags: mysql, git, export

Is there a way I can utilize git to export/download my MySQL development database that is utilized in my code on a commit or some other way through git so that whenever I clone my project, I always have a current copy of the database?

If not, I can always export the database, and add it to the source, I was just wondering if git had the capability of doing this almost like a hook.

Comment: Are you actually saying you want to copy your entire database after *each* commit?

Comment: This would be a cop-out of an answer, but you can learn about git hooks in the excellent Pro Git book that is available free online. Here's the link directly to that chapter: http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html

Comment: Maybe not commit, but after every push (something I only do when I am done with a release branch).  I'm guessing that githooks (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) is my best bet?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up using the git hooks as I anticipated.  I created the `pre-commit` hook and added the following to it:

```
#!/bin/bash
DBUSER="sysbackup"
DBPASS="password"
DB="database-name"
SCHEMAPATH="DBSchema"

mysqldump -u $DBUSER -p$DBPASS $DB > $SCHEMAPATH/$DB.sql
git add $SCHEMAPATH/$DB.sql
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. What is `exit 0` for? AFAIK, when the script ends, it exits with status 0, doesn't it?

Comment: It tells the shell that MY script is exiting with a value of 0.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't every script return with an exit code of 0 when there isn't an `exit` statement? What I mean: AFAIK you don't need to explicitly call `exit 0` at the very end of any script.